# How do I convert a character to integer within a PostgreSQL (9.1) function?

Tags: postgresql, types, casting, postgresql-9.1

I have this following code:

```
BEGIN
   x := split_part(text, ',', 1);
   UPDATE albumphoto SET order = 1 WHERE idtable = 1 AND idx = x;   
END
```

But my column table named `idx` is a numeric type, and the `split_part` returns a character type to the variable `x`. I've tried using `CAST`, but I don't know how to use it properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Like this:

```
UPDATE albumphoto SET order = 1 WHERE idtable = 1 AND idx = CAST (x AS INTEGER);
```

(Use appropriate numeric type instead of `INTEGER`).

Answer (score 8):

Or simpler:

```sql
UPDATE albumphoto
SET    "order" = 1
WHERE  idtable = 1
AND    idx = split_part(text, ',', 1)::int  -- cast to actual type (if not a string type)
AND    "order" IS DISTINCT FROM 1;
```

`expression::type` is the simple (non-SQL-standard) Postgres way to cast. Details in the manual in the chapter [Type Casts](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-expressions.html#SQL-SYNTAX-TYPE-CASTS).
More about [data types in PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/datatype.html).

The last predicate I added is useful if `"order"` could already *be* `1`, in which case the update wouldn't change anything - at full cost. Rather do nothing instead. Related (see last paragraph):

- [How do I (or can I) SELECT DISTINCT on multiple columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54418/how-do-i-or-can-i-select-distinct-on-multiple-columns/12632129#12632129)

And you don't *need* a variable.